# Selecting the bounds for integrating a joint probability density function with dependent variables

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint probability density function given by
$f (x, y) = k(1 − y),\  0 ≤ x ≤ y ≤ 1$; $0$, elsewhere.

a) Find the value of $k$ that makes this a probability density function.

b) Find $P(X ≤ 3/4, Y ≥ 1/2)$.

I solved the first part, the answer is $K=6$. For the second part, I tried to draw a diagram to help me understand the problem; a two dimensional triangle out of the three dimensional space where $f(x,y)$ is positive. However, I'm having trouble in interpreting the region to determine the bounds for integrating the density function. What I really need to learn is what are the bounds, and how were they determined. According to the solution, there are two separate double integrals, and I get the idea that there must be two separate regions, but I still can't visualize it. It'd help if you could draw or indicate the relevant region to illustrate the solution. I would appreciate any answer that helps me understand the question better, if needed, I can provide the solution as it is in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X must be less than min(3/4, Y) while Y can range from 1/2 to 1, so you should break up the integral into a case for $Y \le 3/4$ and $Y \ge 3/4$.

You don't need to picture it in 3-D, but if you want to, start with the triangular region above the $Y=X$ line in the X-Y plane.  Then the height above the paper doesn't depend on $X$, but it is max for low $Y$ and goes to zero as $Y$ goes to 1 linearly, so the cross-section in the Z-Y plane is triangular.  That's the whole region for the first part.  Then for the second part, you're only going to consider the part bounded from below by $Y = 1/2$ and $X=3/4$, so that's trapezoidal region  in the x-y plane while still a wedge.

[image: f(x,y)]

Here's the R script that makes that picture if you want to play with it. You can rotate it around by changing theta and phi.

```
x = seq(0,1,.01)
y = x
z = function(x,y) ifelse(x = 1/2, 6*(1-y),0)
f = outer(x,y,z)
persp(x, y, f, theta = 70, phi = 45, expand = 1, col = "white", ticktype="detailed")
```